# how to avoid deadlocks with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, database-deadlocks

I just learnt that when I create a relationship between 2 nodes in neo4j, both of them are locked (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-locking.html).
However, in our project, we have elements that we can instanciate and we finnaly have two nodes in the graph linked by a "INSTANCE_OF" relationship.
For exemple if I instanciate element B, I have a new element B1. They are stored in the graph like B<-INSTANCE_OF-B1.
My problem is that many users can instanciate element B on same time and it result in deadlocks.
How can I avoid these deadlocks please ? I don't need to write properties on B, I just want to "attach" B1 to B in my graph. Is having a property in B1 reprensenting the B id would be a better solution instead of linking them with a relationship ? I think it wouldn't since we lost all the graph interest, but I really don't know how to avoid theses deadlocks ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4):

You have two strategies:

the first, a pessimistic one, is using the `LockManager` *getWriteLock* method to acquire an exclusive lock on the node B before adding the related B1 node and unlock it as soon as the relationship creation finishes;

the second, an optimistic one, is to implement a retry strategy in case of deadlock, you can catch the `DeadlockDetectedException` exception and retry the operation until it's successful.

Comment: I tried the second strategie and indeed it works very well, thanks a lot. But I didn't achieve to use the first one. Indeed, graphDatabaseAPI.getLockManager() which allows me to get the LockManager is deprecated and I can't find the new way to do it. Can you tell me that please ? Thank you.

Comment: Seems that in 2.0.0 release the new way of acquiring locks is by means of the *Transaction.acquireWriteLock* method, look at [documentation](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) for a better explanation.

Comment: I am using node.js REST API to connect to Neo4j. Do you think we can handle exception?