# Neo4J - How to avoid this lock issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-node

I got this error when I tried to delete two different relationships from a node concurrently.

`{ [Error: LockClient[402733] can't wait on resource RWLock[RELATIONSHIP(201056), hash=1039491204] since => LockClient[402733] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(131064), hash=949197283] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[402732] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[RELATIONSHIP(201056), hash=1039491204]]
  message: 'LockClient[402733] can\'t wait on resource RWLock[RELATIONSHIP(201056), hash=1039491204] since => LockClient[402733] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(131064), hash=949197283] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[402732] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[RELATIONSHIP(201056), hash=1039491204]' }`

Is this expected? how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this if your code uses consistent ordering of the stuff to delete, e.g. by node/relationship ids.

Comment: 1) match (a{id:1})-[r1:r]->(b{id:2}) delete r1;  2) match (a{id:1})-[r2:r]->(c{id:3}) delete r2.     1) and 2) can run concurrently. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your answer

Comment: by setting a property you'd grab a write lock. So doing `match (a{id:1})-[r1:r]->(b{id:2}) set a.dummyProp=1 delete r` should make sure a write lock is first grabbed on a and then r is deleted.

Comment: Thank you. How about trying again if we detect 'DeadlockDetectedException'  as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495549/how-to-avoid-deadlocks-with-neo4j  ?

Comment: That's the other solution. The original question was how to avoid it. Catching deadlockexcptions and retrying might be the least invasive solution however.

Comment: Thank you. I felt setting dummy property like a.dummyProp is extra overhead for each writes, trying again on deadlock exception or Transaction.acquireWriteLock() may be better.